# Black text with Adwaita GTK+ theme

Tags: lubuntu, themes, gtk

With Lubuntu 21.10, I'm unclear how I can customize much about the appearance of GTK applications. `lxqt-config-appearance` appears to be able to change some GTK settings if you check the "Set GTK themes" box, but not all.

What I want to achieve for GTK dialogs and menus is black text on a gray background, similar to the theme Adwaita, but with literally black text (#000000) rather than dark gray. The HighContrast theme provides black text, but it also makes window backgrounds white, so they no longer contrast properly (ah, irony) with white-backgrounded text areas, like the message body of messages in Thunderbird.

Comment: Some applications follow the themes set by the desktop, others don't. There are many issues on theming issues on github (https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/572, 1904, ....) which often have clues.

Comment: For Lubuntu, search for KDE/QT version of your application.